# derivation eigenvector centrality for graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I fail to understand the derivation of the eigenvector centrality.
The lecture notes cited below start with the following formula that says we can compute the degree centrality for a node $i$ in a graph $G = (V,E)$ with length t by this formula,
$$ x_i(t) = \sum_{j} A_{ij}x_j(t-1)$$
if we recursively compute it and starting with $x(0)$ which is a vector with length $|V|$ and all entries are 1.

In matrix and vector notation:
$$x(t) = Ax(t-1) = A^t x(0)$$

Then it is assumed $x(0)$ can be reformulated as a linear combination of the
eigenvalues of A (why can we do this?)
$$x(0) = \sum_{k} c_k v_k$$
where $v_k$ is a eigenvector of adjacency matrix $A$ and what is $c_k$?

Subsequently

$$x(t) = A^t \sum_{k} c_k v_k = \sum_{k} c_k v_k \lambda^t_{k}$$

Why is this allowed? My background in linear algebra is not sufficient for this step, can somebody cite the rule or explain the reason?

Sources:
http://faculty.nps.edu/rgera/MA4404/Winter2020/06-CentralitiesEigenvector.pdf
[http://www.pitt.edu/~kpele/Materials15/module2.pdf](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Ekpele/Materials15/module2.pdf)